# Handling checkBox in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My Page has single checkBox for two fields each and I need to pass the option to check or not as a generic method. Tried with if else loop and switch case but not working.

My Code:

```
public void checkBoxClick(String checkBox, String propName){
    switch (checkBox) {
        case "Checked":
            WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name(propName));
            element.click();
            break;
        case "UnChecked":
            break;
    }
}
```

Step-define file:

```
@Then("^Enter (.*) also check (.*) and (.*)$")
public void enter_rucNo_check_transit(String checkBox1, String checkBox2) throws InterruptedException {
    driver_interactions.checkBoxClick("mrclBulkHeader.transit", checkBox1);
    driver_interactions.checkBoxClick("mrclBulkHeader.airTransit", checkBox2);
}
```

I don't know why the checkBox doesn't get click. Can anyone correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here method that will check or uncheck your checkbox:

```
public void checkBoxSelect(String propName, boolean select){
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name(propName));
    if (element.isSelected() != select) {
        element.click();
}
```

If you want to check and checkbox not checked, it will do it. If checkbox already checked will do nothing:

```
checkBoxSelect("checkboxname", true);
```

If you want to ucheck and checkbox not unchecked already, it will do it. If checkbox already unchecked will do nothing:

```
checkBoxSelect("checkboxname", false);
```

Your step will be:

```
@Then("^Enter (.*) also check (.*) and (.*)$")
public void enter_rucNo_check_transit(String checkBox1, String checkBox2) throws InterruptedException {
    driver_interactions.checkBoxSelect("mrclBulkHeader.transit", true);
    driver_interactions.checkBoxSelect("mrclBulkHeader.airTransit", true);
}
```

In my opinion separate them will be better:

```
@Then("^Set  value of  \"Transit\" checkbox to (.*)$")
public void enter_rucNo_check_transit(String check) throws InterruptedException {
    driver_interactions.checkBoxSelect("mrclBulkHeader.transit", string.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
@Then("^Set value of \"Air Transit\" checkbox to (.*)$")
public void enter_rucNo_check_transit(String check) throws InterruptedException {
    driver_interactions.checkBoxSelect("mrclBulkHeader.airTransit", string.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

Are you locating checkboxes by name attribute "mrclBulkHeader.transit" and "mrclBulkHeader.airTransit"? Please share your html?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void checkBoxClick(String propName,String checkBox ){
    switch (checkBox) {
        case "Checked":
            WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name(propName));
            element.click();
            break;
        case "UnChecked":
            break;
    }
}
```